# Discord.js Voice: cannot play ytdl stream

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to play YT audio via Discord.js/voice and ytdl.
I've this code (in the play command)

```
...
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        // console.log(args, voiceChannel)
        if (!voiceChannel)
          return message.channel.send(
            "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!"
          ); 
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
          return message.channel.send(
            "I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!"
          );
        }

        const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
        const song = {
            title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
            url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
        };
        console.log(song)

        let conn = await voice.joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: voiceChannel.id,
            guildId: message.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            selfDeaf: false,
            selfMute: false
        })
        let conn2= voice.getVoiceConnection(voiceChannel.id)
        console.log(conn2)
        const stream = ytdl(song.url)
        conn2.subscribe(stream)
...
```

The bot has all the perms, joins correctly in the channel where i am, but at the line with  `conn2.subscribe(stream)` gives the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
    at Object.execute (%mypath%\musicbot2\commands\play.js:39:15)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

And i cannot find anything about this error. How can i correctly play music/audio? In this case with ytdl, but also with other sites, and packages.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [`getVoiceConnection`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/modules.html#getvoiceconnection) function takes a guild id, not a channel id.

Changing it to this should work:

```js
let conn2 = voice.getVoiceConnection(message.guild.id)
```

Comment: ok yes my bad it does not give error anymore, but it still gives error at `conn2.subscribe(stream)` with error `.subscribe() is not a function`

Comment: Try adding a semi-colon after it

Comment: Same, ".subscribe is not a function"

Comment: Try console logging `conn2` and `conn2.subscribe` (without brackets)